# How to reset a value inside a setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `setInterval` of jquery to change `img` `src` after every 3 seconds. It works but I don't want it to stop but continue. For example, I have given it an array of images names and it pick each name and put it in source. I am checking the index no with the array's length i.e. if less than continue else not.

Upon meeting the condition, I want to restart it automatically but I don't know, how?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;
    var imagesArr = ["p.png", "White.png"];
    var arrLength = imagesArr.length;

    setInterval(function ()
    {
        if (index < arrLength)
        {
            $("#imgSlider").attr("src", "/Content2/img/" + imagesArr[index]);
        }


       // alert(index);

        index++;
    }, 3000);

</script>
```

update:

put else condition, but not working.

```
  else
        {
            index = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Hint: reset `index` based on conditional

Comment: @charlietfl: I am doing now but after that it doesn't change the images.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (index == arrLength) {
      index = 0;
    }
```

Placing this below your increment (index++) would reset the index right after it acted on the final element in the array. However the cleanest way to do what you want would be to say "else { }" right after your existing if statement and resetting the index there, and since you want to then start from 0 and not execute the "index++", I would place "index++" inside your if statement so it only executes while your index is still less than the length of the array.

Comment: done. thanks a lot.